# How to form a url request for a web service designed in .net

Tags: .net, web-services, http

I have a below webservice design

```
POST /films/FilmApp.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/getFilms"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getFilms xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <s1>string</s1>
    </getFilms>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For above web service request, I am trying to initiate a http call and use that in my mobile application. I am parsing in my http request as

```
http://myhost.com/films/FilmApp.asmx/getFilms?s1=inception
```

For above request I am getting response as

```
http://myhost.com/Errorpage.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/films/FilmApp.asmx/getFilms.
```

I am expecting a XML response as below

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <getFilmsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <getFilmsResult>xml</getFilmsResult>
    </getFilmsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

../films/FilmApp.asmx/getFilms is a valid path and I am not able to understand why I am getting this error. Is there is something wrong with my http request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `http://myhost.com/films/FilmApp.asmx/getFilms?s1=inception` only works [from the browser for testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719483.aspx) purposes when you also have this [enabled in your configuration](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;819267) file:

```
<system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
</system.web>
```

**The SOAP endpoint where you need to POST is  `http://myhost.com/films/FilmApp.asmx`**.